# pattern matching in Bash of Linux

Tags: linux, bash, sed

Does anybody know how to delete the pattern "@TechCrunch:" in the following str by sed in Linux?

```
str="0,RT @TechCrunch: The Tyranny Of Government And Our Duty Of Confidentiality As Bloggers."
```

So the desired output will be:

```
"0,RT The Tyranny Of Government And Our Duty Of Confidentiality As Bloggers."
```

I tried many ways but no one works, e.g:

```
echo $str | sed 's/@[a-zA-Z]*\ //'
```

Comment: Get your pattern right and that command works. You missed the `:` after `Crunch`.

Comment: Also you don't need to escape the space in the pattern.

Comment: If you just want to delete everything up to and including the first `: `, you don't need sed for that all. `str=${str#*: }`

Comment: ...or, to just delete that one substring: `str=${str//@TechCrunch: /}`

Comment: ...or, using extglobs (`shopt -s extglob` to enable): `str="${str//@+([[:alpha:]]): /}"`

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed` (or any other external tool) for a single line that's already in a shell variable is hideously inefficient. Much easier to have the shell do the replacement itself.

```
#!/bin/bash
#      ^- must be /bin/bash, not /bin/sh, for extglobs to be available

shopt -s extglob # put this somewhere early in your script to enable extended globs

str="0,RT @TechCrunch: The Tyranny Of Government And Our Duty Of Confidentiality As Bloggers."
echo "${str//@+([[:alpha:]]): /}"
```

This uses [extglob](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#extglob) syntax to provide more powerful pattern matches with built-in shell pattern matching; `+(foo)` is the extglob equivalent to the regex form `(foo)+`.

Answer (score 1):

You were close - just missing the `:`.

```
perl -pe 's/@\w*:\s//i'
```

Or in `sed`:

```
sed -e 's/@[a-z]: //i'
```

Comment: `\s` is PCRE syntax, no? Is a POSIX sed required to support it?

Comment: It is, and it worked on the linux system I tried it on.

Comment: "Works on one system I tested it with" is hardly a way to be confident something will work for anyone but you. Lots of different Linux distros with lots of different toolchains (including tiny ones like Busybox).

Comment: If it were some niche feature, then I might agree. But support for ERE or PCRE isn't exactly unusual. RHEL isn't a niche linux; gnu sed supports it with `-r`. And at a pinch - `perl` isn't exactly uncommon either.

Comment: ERE is very common, but by default requires the `-r` argument to enable in GNU sed (otherwise, behavior is BRE). PCRE is an off-by-default compile-time feature even in GNU sed. `\s` may be supported even in "BRE" on some modern GNU systems, but... well, this is where we get back to whether depending on extensions is a good idea. :)

Comment: Noticed, and upvoted (though why the `-i` option in the perl version, when the question indicates no intent to do in-place edits)?

Comment: Force of habit mostly.

Answer (score 0):

`:` is not matched by `[a-zA-Z]`. Also, there's no need to backslash the space.

```
sed 's/@[a-zA-Z]*: //'
```